# openweathermap json to csv

Tags: csv, json

I need to convert some json containing forecast data to csv (for use in gnuplot). Have tried a couple of json2csv utilities

json sample:

```
{"cod":"200","message":0.006,"cnt":40,"list":[{"dt":1519333200,"main":{"temp":271.62,"temp_min":271.62,"temp_max":272.921,"pressure":1028.3,"sea_level":1037.2,"grnd_level":1028.3,"humidity":88,"temp_kf":-1.3},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":4.86,"deg":78.004},"rain":{},"snow":{},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2018-02-22 21:00:00"},{"dt":1519344000,"main":{"temp":271.22,"temp_min":271.22,"temp_max":272.193,"pressure":1028.11,"sea_level":1037.04,"grnd_level":1028.11,"humidity":100,"temp_kf":-0.98},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":4.52,"deg":80.0016},"rain":{},"snow":{},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2018-02-23 00:00:00"},
```

Same pretty-printed:

```
{
  "cod": "200",
  "message": 0.006,
  "cnt": 40,
  "list": [
    {
      "dt": 1519333200,
      "main": {
        "temp": 271.62,
        "temp_min": 271.62,
        "temp_max": 272.921,
        "pressure": 1028.3,
        "sea_level": 1037.2,
        "grnd_level": 1028.3,
        "humidity": 88,
        "temp_kf": -1.3
      },
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 800,
          "main": "Clear",
          "description": "clear sky",
          "icon": "01n"
        }
      ],
      "clouds": {
        "all": 0
      },
      "wind": {
        "speed": 4.86,
        "deg": 78.004
      },
      "rain": {},
      "snow": {},
      "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
      },
      "dt_txt": "2018-02-22 21:00:00"
    },
    {
      "dt": 1519344000,
      "main": {
        "temp": 271.22,
        "temp_min": 271.22,
        "temp_max": 272.193,
        "pressure": 1028.11,
        "sea_level": 1037.04,
        "grnd_level": 1028.11,
        "humidity": 100,
        "temp_kf": -0.98
      },
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 800,
          "main": "Clear",
          "description": "clear sky",
          "icon": "01n"
        }
      ],
      "clouds": {
        "all": 0
      },
      "wind": {
        "speed": 4.52,
        "deg": 80.0016
      },
      "rain": {},
      "snow": {},
      "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
      },
      "dt_txt": "2018-02-23 00:00:00"
    },
```

I've managed to use json2csv to flatten the data (and cut the first few unneeded fields):

```
1519333200 271.62 271.62 272.921 1028.3 1037.2 1028.3 88 -1.3 800 "Clear" "clear sky" "01n" 0 4.86 78.004 "{}" "{}" "n"
"2018-02-22 21:00:00" 1519344000 271.22 271.22 272.193 1028.11 1037.04 1028.11 100 -0.98 800 "Clear" "clear sky" "01n" 0 4.52 80.0016 "{}" "{}"
"n" "2018-02-23 00:00:00"
```

I need either creating the new lines after the plain text date (sed??) or ideally flattening the json directly to csv

Comment: It's unclear what values you want from the JSON document.  It would be fairly easy to extract the wanted values with something like `jq -r '.list[]|[.dt, .main.temp]|@csv' file` and then feed them directly into Gnuplot.

Answer (score 6):

Regular expressions and `sed` aren't a great match for this kind of task, but it's fairly simple using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), a JSON processing tool:

```
$ jq -r '.list[]|[.dt, .main[]] | @csv' < data.json
1519333200,271.62,271.62,272.921,1028.3,1037.2,1028.3,88,-1.3
1519344000,271.22,271.22,272.193,1028.11,1037.04,1028.11,100,-0.98
```

`jq` takes in a JSON data stream and filters it to extract the data you want, analogously to `sed` but for structured data rather than text. This command takes [each element of the "list" array (`.list[]`)](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Array/ObjectValueIterator:.[]) and [plucks out the "dt" field (`.dt`)](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ObjectIdentifier-Index:.foo,.foo.bar) of [the object inside](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Pipe:%7C) along with everything in the "main" object too (`.main[]`), putting the whole lot into an array and [converting that to a CSV row (`@csv`)](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Formatstringsandescaping).

---

If you're interested in particular fields, or you want to reorder them, you can list them out too:

```
$ jq -r '.list[]|[.dt, .main.temp_min, .main.humidity] | @csv' < data.json
1519333200,271.62,88
1519344000,271.22,100
```

Just list out each one you care about and ignore the rest.

---

If you want to get into other parts of the data, you can put that in there too: `.clouds` will look into the `clouds` field, or you can read the wind speed with `.wind.speed` - always a dot before the name, like you were writing JavaScript. [The `jq` manual is quite comprehensive](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) for whatever custom behaviour you need.

Comment: Thank you @Michael - that's an excellent answer. I wasn't familiar with jq (I have a lot to learn!)
But I still have one problem; I can extract most of the arrays, but I'm getting an error on the `"weather" array - 'object ({"id":800,"...) is not valid in a csv row'`.
I'm using: `jq '.list[]|[.dt, .main[], .weather[], .clouds[], .wind[], .rain[], .snow[]]`

Comment: The weather field is a list of objects, so it's not really clear to me what it even means to convert that to CSV. You can flatten it out with `.weather[].[]` but it'll be variable-length; really it's going to depend on what you actually want out of the conversion.

Comment: Thanks once again.. I see what you mean. I'm only actually interested in `"icon":"xxx"`
I'll have a play over the weekend - I'm very grateful indeed for your very clear help. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick addenda to excelent Michael Homer answer:

If the jq expression becomes large, we can make a script with it:

Example:

```
$ cat mkweatherreport
#!/usr/bin/jq -rf
.list[] |
  [
     .dt,
     .main.temp_min,        # in Kelvin degrees
     .main.humidity
  ] | @csv
```

and then:

```
$ mkweatherreport f.json
1519333200,271.62,88
1519344000,271.22,100
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be easiest if we could first extract the elements of the `list` array, and then convert them to CSV.  We can do that with a combination of `jq` (to extract the individual `list` elements) and `mlr` (to convert these elements to CSV in a convenient way):

```bash
$ jq '.list[]' file | mlr --j2c cat
dt,main.temp,main.temp_min,main.temp_max,main.pressure,main.sea_level,main.grnd_level,main.humidity,main.temp_kf,weather.1.id,weather.1.main,weather.1.description,weather.1.icon,clouds.all,wind.speed,wind.deg,rain,snow,sys.pod,dt_txt
1519333200,271.62,271.62,272.921,1028.3,1037.2,1028.3,88,-1.3,800,Clear,clear sky,01n,0,4.86,78.004,{},{},n,2018-02-22 21:00:00
1519344000,271.22,271.22,272.193,1028.11,1037.04,1028.11,100,-0.98,800,Clear,clear sky,01n,0,4.52,80.0016,{},{},n,2018-02-23 00:00:00
```

The `jq` call would, given the data in the question (corrected to close the array), first produce the equivalent of

```json
{"dt":1519333200,"main":{"temp":271.62,"temp_min":271.62,"temp_max":272.921,"pressure":1028.3,"sea_level":1037.2,"grnd_level":1028.3,"humidity":88,"temp_kf":-1.3},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":4.86,"deg":78.004},"rain":{},"snow":{},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2018-02-22 21:00:00"}
{"dt":1519344000,"main":{"temp":271.22,"temp_min":271.22,"temp_max":272.193,"pressure":1028.11,"sea_level":1037.04,"grnd_level":1028.11,"humidity":100,"temp_kf":-0.98},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":4.52,"deg":80.0016},"rain":{},"snow":{},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2018-02-23 00:00:00"}
```

The call to Miller then reads these individual objects, flattening them out, and converts them to CSV (`--j2c` means *"read JSON, write CSV"*, short for (and added more recently than) `--ijson --ocsv`).

You would modify the `jq` expression to delete or modify the fields from each `list` element that you do not want.  For example, to only return the first element from the `weather` sub-array, you would use `.list[] | .weather |= first`.